# Python PIP filequeue installation error

Tags: python-2.7, pip

I am trying to install a list of packages using a requirements file with PIP in a python virtual environment on Windows.

Halfway thru the list I get the following error. Can someone let me know what the error is  ?

```
(nsr) c:\Users\axxxan\Desktop\Temp>pip install -r requirements.txt
Collecting appdirs==1.4.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Using cached appdirs-1.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting asn1crypto==0.22.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Using cached asn1crypto-0.22.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting backports-abc==0.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Using cached backports_abc-0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting beautifulsoup4==4.6.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Using cached beautifulsoup4-4.6.0-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting behave==1.2.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Using cached behave-1.2.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting boto==2.46.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
  Using cached boto-2.46.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cachetools==2.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
  Using cached cachetools-2.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting certifi==2017.4.17 (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
  Using cached certifi-2017.4.17-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cffi==1.10.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))
  Using cached cffi-1.10.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting chardet==3.0.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 10))
  Using cached chardet-3.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: click==6.7 in c:\users\axxxan\envs\nsr\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 11))
Collecting cryptography==1.8.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 12))
  Using cached cryptography-1.8.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting dill==0.2.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 13))
  Using cached dill-0.2.6.zip
Obtaining dp_workflow from git+https://source.developers.google.com/p/txxx-data-lake-core-dev/r/nxx-dp@c6d58a36a3d5bed58333d5057633b789a99a6530#egg=dp_workflow (from -r requirements.txt (line 14))
  Skipping because already up-to-date.
Collecting enum34==1.1.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 15))
  Using cached enum34-1.1.6-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting filequeue==0.3.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 16))
  Using cached filequeue-0.3.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\axxxan\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-jqwnqf\filequeue\setup.py", line 16, in <module>
        long_description = "\n\n".join((read("README.rst"), read("CHANGES.rst"))),
      File "c:\users\axxxan\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-jqwnqf\filequeue\setup.py", line 6, in read
        return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname)).read()
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\axxxan\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-jqwnqf\\filequeue\\CHANGES.rst'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\axxxan\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-jqwnqf\filequeue\
```

Comment: It looks like the filequeue package has a bug: it's setup.py file doesn't correspond with the actual data (i.e., the missing CHANGES.rst file).

Comment: Your [Related GitHub issue](https://github.com/GP89/FileQueue/issues/3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filequeue is missing the `CHANGES.rst` in its tar file on PyPI. This causes pip to fall over, since the `setup.py` requires `CHANGES.rst` (indirectly only).
Given the date of the last update in Jan 2013, a fix may be some time away. A simple workaround is as follows:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/GP89/FileQueue.git
```

*before* you install any of the other packages that depend on it.

Then, during the installation of other packages that require filequeue, pip should find it already installed and skip to the next package to install.

---

Note: a recent fix has solved this problem, and filequeue 0.3.2 should install without problems using pip.